# Xpath is only giving me the first item whereas I want all of them (with Scrapy)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape the results from [this page (Booking)](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAQoggJCEHNlYXJjaF_lpKfpmKrluIJIFVgEaE2IAQGYARW4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AqXw-usFwAIB&sid=99d1716767a9d25ee820122238489b00&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_year_month_monthday=2019-10-15&checkout_year_month_monthday=2019-10-16&city=-240905&class_interval=1&dest_id=-240905&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&lang=en-gb&no_rooms=1&offset=0&postcard=0&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&soz=1&srpvid=87de9c92c893006c&ss=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%B8%82&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&top_ufis=1&lang_click=top&cdl=ja&lang_changed=1&nflt=). The idea is to get all the Urls to all the hotels in the page.

In my Spider in Scrapy I put :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BookingScoreSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

def parse(self, response):
    global url
    print(response.xpath('normalize-space(//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]/@href)'))
    for hotelurl in response.xpath('normalize-space(//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]/@href)'):
        url = response.urljoin(hotelurl.extract())
        print(url)
```

But the loop seems to contain only contains one element (the first hotel)...So the spider is working, I get the URL of the first hotel, but the loop doesn't go on, as if the spider found only one  with class "hotel_name_link url"...
When I check the webpage, yet, I find many such items.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using XPath 1.0 (sadly, scrapy is using 20-year old technology here) and in XPath 1.0, normalize-space() applied to a node-set ignores all but the first node in the node-set. (In XPath 3.1, the current version, you could do `//a[...] ! normalize-space()` which would apply it to each of the nodes and return a sequence of strings.

Your best bet is probably to take out the normalize-space(), return the unnormalized nodes, and then process them in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

When called on a node set, `normalize-space()` will only be applied to the first node.

If you only need to extract the links, a simple workaround would be something like this (indentation added using a pretty-printing function):

```
>>> response.xpath('//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]').xpath('normalize-space(@href)').getall()
[
    '/hotel/jp/hoteruwbfnanbahei-men.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/the-lively-osaka.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/apahoteru-rizoto-yu-tang-jin-ben-ting-yi-tawa.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/apollo-couples-apartment-at-namba.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/dotonbori-apartment-next-jr-namba.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/sotetsu-fresa-inn-osaka-namba.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/chuan-huose-mei-guo-cun.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/da-ban-di-yi-hoteru.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/hotel-wbf-namba-bunraku.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/amp-and-hostel-honmachi-east.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/unizo-inn-shin-osaka.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/hotel-wbf-honmachi.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/chuan-flat-xin-zhai-qiao-dong.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/hiyori-hotel-osaka-namba.en-gb.html',
    '/hotel/jp/noum-osaka.en-gb.html'
]
```

If you need to follow these links, you can just use [response.follow()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow) with a link node, and it will do the right thing.

```
for link in response.xpath('//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]'):
    yield response.follow(link)
```